# Fetching too many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, react-hooks, create-react-app

Im creating a side project for fun in react with create-react-app. I created a hook thats supposed to fetch some information in json and it does the job, the problem is that for some reason its sending a request per item in the json and this is a json with 700+ items, is it a re-render situation? Is it because I'm not using useEffect?

```
export const useFetchQL = (url: URL): Array<Object> => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getData = async () => {
        let query = `
        query {
          characters{
            id 
            name 
            title 
            imageURL 
            leaderSkill 
            passive 
            categories 
            links
          }
        }`;
        let response = await fetch(url,{
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({query}),
        })
        let data = await response.json();
        setData(data.data.characters)
    }
    getData();  
    return data;
}
```

I tried calling it in different parts of the project and nothing, same output. What's happening here and how do I avoid it?

I only need/want to fetch this information once so I can start using it. I would like to post IMG but I cant.

```
import './App.css';
import Cards from './components/Cards';
import Team from './components/Team';
import Search from './components/Search';
import { AddToTeamProvider } from './context/addToTeamContext';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useFetchQL } from './hooks/useFetchQL.ts';

function App() {
  const [chars, setChars] = useState([]);
  setChars(useFetchQL('https://dokkanapi.azurewebsites.net/graphql'));
  console.log(chars);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddToTeamProvider>
        <Team/>
        <Search/>
        <Cards/>
      </AddToTeamProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Every time you call `setChars(...)` in the render phase of your component, your component will rerender, so `App` gets executed again. You have the same issue within `useFetchQL()`. You should use `useEffect()` to fetch your data on mount of your component, so you don't end up continously fetching data and updating your state. You can look at implementations of [`useFetch()`](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-fetch) for ideas

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is not the way you should write hook and use them.
This is more a regular function that returns data after API is finished. You tried to combine API hook pattern with regular function.

Also you are calling it in the main render flow and it will call it many times since you are setting state every time component rerenders.

Here is the one example how you can do this:

```js
export const getQL = async (url: URL): Array<Object> => {
  let query = `
        query {
          characters{
            id 
            name 
            title 
            imageURL 
            leaderSkill 
            passive 
            categories 
            links
          }
        }`;
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
  });

  return response.json();
};
```

And than use this method in a `useEffect` in your component:

```js
import "./App.css";
import Cards from "./components/Cards";
import Team from "./components/Team";
import Search from "./components/Search";
import { AddToTeamProvider } from "./context/addToTeamContext";
import { useState } from "react";
import { getQL } from "./hooks/useFetchQL.ts";

function App() {
  const [chars, setChars] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const call = async () => {
      const result = await getQL("https://dokkanapi.azurewebsites.net/graphql");

      setChars(result);
    };

    call();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AddToTeamProvider>
        <Team />
        <Search />
        <Cards />
      </AddToTeamProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put your  getData() in [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook with an empty dependency array to only run it run once (or alternatively with the "url" prop, which should refetch once you change the url prop in the parent component)

Comment: Actually, since `getQL` is a imported function it will never trigger `useEffect` since it is always the same reference.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding. I meant for the original design in question, if the getData() is put in useEffect (inside the hook), wouldn't that solve the recursive fetch?

I mean apart from if it's a good practice to make it a hook or not.
I personally use hooks for queries, however with also loading and error variables returned as well. I use useEffect inside these hooks. However I do maintain a function for the query (so the hook is just a wrapper) as in some cases it is just better to use a function. From what I understand your solution is a not hook anymore, but a simple function.

Comment: Got it, i agree. With same solution you gotta have dependency to stop it being called  every time. But OPs code is a bit messing with multiple paradigms at once